# cocos2d scene retaining issue

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uibutton, release, scene

There is a scene in my application which has only two labels and a menu item. When I load this scene using `replaceScene` method it stays for 3-4 seconds and then gets disappeared or released. I want to keep it until cancel button is pressed. How can I do it? code is:

```
@implementation MyLayer

+ (id)myScene {

    CCScene *aScene = [CCScene node];
    MYLayer *myLayer = [MyLayer node];
    [aScene addChild:myLayer];

    return aScene;  
}
- (id) init {

    if (self = [super init]) {
           //labels and menu here    
    }
    return self;
}
```

And I am calling it from another scene like this:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [MyLayer myScene]];
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted so it must be somewhere else ...

Comment: @Lukman: Thanks for considering the question but I long resolved it. I am using pushScene instead of replace and it's working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that it's your first scene. Then you should use `runWithScene` method of `CCDirector`.

Comment: we can't run another scene while one is already running, it must be replaced. This scene is terminating the whole application without error. I even made transition from this scene to UIViewController but it's still terminating.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint in MyLayer dealloc method. If it triggers - take a look at a call stack to see who called him

Comment: what i figured out up till now is the difference in how you initialize scene and layers. One method uses node and other init. To replace scene we need the latter one and destroy everything in previous layers. But this gives another problem that screen is filled with a funky pink layer. many people are facing the same situation. Also, i think all sprites are on place under that pink layer because i could click buttons i placed on that layer. Let's see if i can get rid of this pink layer. I'll try your suggestion od dealloc as well but i don't think dealloc is always called when we need it :)

Answer (score 0):

did you try replacing that scene with a "empty" init function to see if it still releases itself? It might be because of the amount of textures you are putting into memory

I did have sort of similar problems before because the images used in the new scene is too big and got auto purged by my app delegate, thus returning me an empty scene sometimes